# formatting a cell in a column if it is an exact match to a cell in a separate column

Tags: google-docs

I want to put a strike-through in column G if it matches the cell next to it in column F (column G is a verification of F).  I found a couple formats but for some reason certain cells are not crossing off even though they match while other cells are.

Right now I have formatted G to

```
=COUNTIF(G:G,F1)
```

I have also tried

```
=COUNTIF(F:F,G1)
```

for column G as well and still some cells will cross off while others don't

Comment: Have you checked for extraneous spaces?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that?

Comment: If a cell has the following content: `"Text "` it will not match `"Text"` because of the extra space at the end (a space could also be at the beginning)

Comment: both cells in each column have a formula associated to them to figure out a dollar amount, so there shouldn't be any extraneous space.  but for whatever reason, it's only crossing off certain cells in column G even though all cells in Column G match the same row cell in Column F

Comment: Are you trying to apply the conditional formatting to the cell if it matches just the cell to the left of it, or if it matches any cell in the column to the left? The use of "matches the cell" doesn't match up with the formulas.

Comment: Please add a screenshot or any visual help so we can really understand what you're trying to do

Comment: I'm not sure how to attach a screenshot?  I'm new to this website.

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler formula is:

```
=G1=F1
```

provided your *Applies to range* starts from G1.